# MODx revolution + spiefeed snippet stripHtmlTags why doesn't work?

Tags: modx

How to strip tags in MODx + spiefeed?

```
[[spieFeed? &setFeedUrl=`https://news.google.com/news?cf=all&hl=ru&pz=1&ned=ru_ru&q=Уголовный кодекс&output=rss`&dateFormat=`d/m/Y H:i`&stripHtmlTags=`"table", "a"`]]
```

and doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Apply this patch - https://github.com/goldsky/spiefeed/pull/16/files if you using version 1.6.1 or prior
2. Use

   ```
   &stripHtmlTags=`table,tr,td,a`
   ```